# Usage of members of a strongly typed enum in a member function's default arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, strongly-typed-enum

I am using G++ mostly and nowadays Visual Studio 2015.
I wanted to build my project with VC++2015 but I get error messages that saying invalid use of '::' in a function given default arguments with a forward declared strongly typed enum.

Here is some code:

```
struct Foo
{
    //! Forward declaration of Bar
    enum class Bar : short;

    //! "Faulty" function with default argument
    void DoSmth(Bar aBar = Bar::Baz)
    {
        // ... code ...
    }

    //! Complete declaration of Bar
    enum class Bar : short
    {
        Baz
    };
};

int main() { }
```

It gives me the following error at the declaration of the function DoSmth() with the default argument Bar::Baz:

```
test.cpp(7): error C2589: '::': illegal token on right side of '::'
test.cpp(7): error C2059: syntax error: '::'
test.cpp(17): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

With G++ (tested with 4.9 and 5.1) the code compiles just fine but with VC++2015 it doesn't.

Im fully aware that I have to declare something before usage but.
Is it just because that VC++2015 does not look within the scope of the class for the complete declaration and definition of Bar but G++ does?
Or maybe does G++ just take the complete declaration and "merges" it with the forward declaration (as they are in the same scope) and thus makes it completely available to the class?
Or maybe I am just plain wrong and something complete different causes this?

I can live with it that I have to change all my declarations for strongly typed enums in order to make it work with VC++2015.

But I also want to know why this is?

Comment: Does no one knows an answer or have at least an idea?

Comment: It's a good idea to include the `c++` tag with your question; I think not having it has reduced the visibility of your question considerably.

Comment: As explained in the answer, I think this is a bug. Do you want to report it yourself, or should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is valid, and VC 14 is wrong to reject it.

According to [N4527](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf), the current Standard working draft, [9.2p2]:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or
>   complete type) at the closing `}` of the *class-specifier*. Within the
>   class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete within
>   function bodies, default arguments, *using-declarations* introducing
>   inheriting constructors (12.9), *exception-specifications*, and
>   *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members (including
>   such things in nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete
>   within its own class *member-specification*.

Within the default argument, finding `Bar::Baz` requires the full definition of `Bar`, which is available in the complete class, so everything's fine.

Comment: Ok that was the same i thought!  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a workaround for now is to move the complete definition of the `enum class` to be before the function call to `DoSmith()`.